# Having a static com.google.inject.Injector

Tags: java, dependency-injection

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

We are declaring a static `Injector` in `OurGuiceServletConfig` (subclass of `com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener`). Though `contextInitialized()` is called only once during the initialisation of `ServletContextListener`, additionally we are initialising it within `synchronized` block, just to ensure the thread safety.

```
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import com.google.inject.Guice;
    import com.google.inject.Injector;
    import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;
    import com.company.services.ServicesCleanup;
    ....

    public class OurGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
                private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OurGuiceServletConfig.class);
                public static Injector injector; //Wonder whether its ok to have a static injector?

                @Override
                public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
                    super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent); //super.contextInitialized() calls the overridden getInjector()
                }


                @Override
                protected Injector getInjector() {
                    LOG.info("getInjector()");
                    synchronized (this) { 
                        if (OurGuiceServletConfig.injector == null) {
                            OurGuiceServletConfig.injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServletsModule(), new OurServicesModule());
                        }
                    }
                    return injector;
                }
                ........

                @Override
                public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent{
                LOG.info("contextDestroyed()");
                super.contextDestroyed(servletContextEvent);
                // Destroying resources
                injector.getInstance(ServicesCleanup.class).close();
            }
        }
```

We are later referring that static variable in `OurRESTResourcesConfig` (subclass of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`):

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;

import com.company.servlets.config.OurGuiceServletConfig;

/**
 * This acts like a bridge between guice injection and hk2
 * 
 *
 */
public class OurRESTResourcesConfig  extends ResourceConfig {
....    
    @Inject
    public OurRESTResourcesConfig(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {

        packages(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());

        LOG.info("Registering injectables..");
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);

        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(OurGuiceServletConfig.injector);
        LOG.info("bridged Guice to HK2..");
    }
}
```

Here are my queries:

1. Is it safer to use a static `Injector`?
2. Is there any better way to do resolve this reference?

Answer (score 3):

The better solution is to actually just use *dependency injection* rather than a static service locator. Service Locator and Dependency Injection are two different ways of solving the same problems -- mixing them seems likely to just cause you pain (besides making it that much harder to test!).

That said, if you really want to do this sort of thing, what you want is `requestStaticInjection()`. See the "Static Injections" section of the [Injections page in the Guide documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) for details.